# Preventing page scroll on Slider Revolution

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a revolution slider v5.x with mouse scroll enabled and some content underneath. The behaviour I want is that the page should remain fixed, with the mouse wheel only scrolling through all the slides. Once the slides are finished the page should scroll down to the remainder of the content. Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more a plugin support question than stack. I'm presuming the current behavior is the content loops after its completed. You could probably alter the code to break the loop after it's completed once, but unless you're very comfortable with coding + securing your alterations it's likely a bad idea. There are a huge amount of vulnerabilities you could potentially open your site to, not to mention Rev had previous security issues on it's own. I noticed your post was down voted so most likely no one will reply on here. I just wanted to offer some advice to maybe point you in the general direction. Hope it works out, good luck